# How do you dynamically reload fish config files as you would in bash?

Tags: shell, configuration-files, fish

I am looking for the equivalent of `source .bashrc` for [Fish](http://fishshell.com).

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Use

```
source ~/.config/fish/config.fish
```

Or, if your fish is older than 2.1 (See [fish#310](http://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/310))

```
. ~/.config/fish/config.fish
```

Then it will be sourced again, so depending on what you have in there it will be reloaded. For example appending to a universal variable would add more entries.

Comment: This now depricated. https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/310 in fish 3 is gone. Also can you might add `~``to the command line

Comment: Thanks @Azd325 for the comment - but wasn't clear what was deprecated! ;) Looking at the link - `.` is deprecated. `source` is still valid.

Comment: My new personally favorite method, assuming Oh My Fish is installed, is `omf reload`.

Comment: Using `omf reload` will also append more entries to a universal variable (as with source `~/.config/fish/config.fish` or running `fish` again.